# Find DocumentId through Discovery GUI tool

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson, watson-discovery

I want to train my Discovery collection where I have already uploaded over 200 documents. I uploaded these documents through the GUI. Looking through the Discovery documentation, I know that I have will have to make API calls to train my collection since the training API has not been exposed through the GUI yet. As part of the training API calls I need to include a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "natural_language_query": "{natural_language_query}",
  "filter": "{filter_definition}"
  "examples": [
    {
      "document_id": "{document_id_1}",
      "cross_reference": "{cross_reference_1}",
      "relevance": 0
    },
    {
      "document_id": "{document_id_2}",
      "cross_reference": "{cross_reference_2}",
      "relevance": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is how should I get the documentIds for the documents that I have already uploaded? Is there a way to find this through the GUI? Or perhaps an API call that will return something like:

```
{
  "document_name" = "MyDocument1",
  "documentId" = "the_document_id_for_MyDocument1"
},

...

{
  "document_name" = "MyDocumentN",
  "documentId" = "the_document_id_for_MyDocumentN"
}
```

Or would the only way to get the documentIds would be to create a new collection and upload all of the documents through API calls directly and track the documentIds as I get them back?

Answer (score 0):

Using the GUI, perform the following steps:

1. Input `term(_id)` in the "Group query results (Aggregation)"
   textbox.
2. Under "Fields to return", select "Specify" to input
   `extracted_metadata`

Note, that query and filter inputs should remain empty

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I tried both `term(_id)` and `term(id)` and both aggregations returned no results. Can you post some examples?